# Unload/Reload javascript or better solution for lots of ajax content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a page with several tabs on it. I'll use two for this example. (Products, Services)

Instead of having the content in these tabs load at run-time, I have them load their specific tab content when the tab is clicked. I have a lot of tabs with a lot of content and it's the only way to have a reasonable initial page/load speed.

Each one of these tabs used to have its own javascript file that loaded after the content loaded. The javascript file is huge and I needed to come up with a universal script file with universal tokens in my data so that I could use the same script file for all of the tabs... Example, instead of a class .viewproductcomments, .viewservicecomments, etc. I have .viewelementcomments for all of them.

This I have successfully accomplished, but it created another problem.

Is there a simple way to "Unload all actions" created by this script file when another tab is clicked, so that it can be reloaded after all the new elements are sent to the page via ajax? I could go through and .on every little thing but the hierarchy level of the .on to capture a static element would be quite a bit up the ladder.

Basically I have a lot of script that needs to be recognized "after" the content loads, and I don't want to reload the same script file for every tab, as this will cause duplicate events or other unknown stuff.

Any advice, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

*** Editing to provide example:

```
$('.post_comments_level1').each(function() {
    var cType = parseInt($(this).parent().prev('div').find('.c-t').text());
    var uniqueID = parseInt($(this).parent().prev('div').find('.un-id').text());
    var listingID = parseInt($(this).parent().prev('div').find('.l-id').text());
    var commentsHome = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyFeeds/Feed.aspx',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            "xfd" : 'Get_Comments',
            "ctype" : cType,
            "unid" : uniqueID,
            "pid" : portalID,
            "lid" : listingID,
            "uid" : userID
        },
        success: function(data) {
            commentsHome.html(data);
            ResetHeight();
        }
    });
});
```

Every "product" for example, has its own set of comments that are wrapped in a UL, and comment elements are LI elements. THe example script finds all the ul with the class .post_comments_level1, retrieves comments from the database via ajax, and inserts those comments within the initially empty ul element.

So when I click on the next tab, say it's services... I can make all of this work the long way, but was looking for a solid method. For example, I now just want that action to take place only on newly added UL in the services tab... Just trying to get my head around the best way to optimize the situation.

Comment: Could any of these "scripts" be events that could possibly be delegated so that they don't need to be re-bound?

Comment: I want to ensure I follow best practices before I go further. I can delegate several things as events. I can make it work, but I have this daunting feeling that I'm mucking up water that doesn't need mucking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to create JavaScript classes with the appropriate methods to minimize the amount of code you're writing to accomplish the same thing.

Example:

Your user clicks the "Products" tab:

```
$('#productsTab').on('click', function(evt){

    //Use classes you've created.
    var blah = new Foo(); 
    });
```

Then you user clicks the "Services" tab:

```
$('#servicesTab').on('click', function(evt){

    //Same function, same methods, is not affected by old one
    var blah2 = new Foo(); 
    });
```

This is a really primitive example of creating classes in JavaScript, but it should get you on the right track: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Edit:

The way I interpreted your question was you asking how to best reuse your code. You described having several tabs with content that was acted upon by JavaScript/jQuery in similar ways.

I suggested that you create a class (which in JavaScript just means a reusable function) to accomplish this task.

If you're having trouble understanding this, maybe this example with help. Look at the code and read the alerts:

http://jsfiddle.net/anb4k/

I created a function called "foo".

I then assigned a variable called "blah" to "new foo();".

"blah" inherits all of "foo"'s functionality, but by using the "new" operator, I've created an entirely different instance of the function. This might help you with your tab issue. Build your code so that the model doesn't matter, then use the function to build your content when the conditions are correct (onClick, or when visible, etc).

Comment: I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this. I edited my question. Would you mind giving me an example based on my edits? Thank you @Trendy!

Comment: @user1447679 Updated, hopefully that helps a bit with your situation.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you for taking the time to help a stranger :)